# How to get "Date Created" and "Date Modified" while using os.walk()

Tags: python, pandas

My company wants to transition from our old *store it in the Engineering Folder* mentality to a PDM. I writing a script that will walk through the directories and log roots, directories, and files.

I've already been able to walk through the directory and do what I want to be able to do with the roots, directories, and files and export/sort/whatever the data. But I want to be able to get the Date Created `st_ctime` and Date Modified `st_mtime`. I've found solutions online that will do a single directory but I want to implement it into my current `os.walk()`.

My goal is, like I've done with the roots, dirs, and files, is to grab the ctime, and mtime and append it into a list that I can concatenate into a dataframe and then manipulate how I want. I just have no idea how to get it.

Below is my code. How can I get the `ctime` & `mtime` and append them to the appropriate lists?

EDIT: I'm using Windows 10

```
global path_to_crawl
self.c = 0
self.roots_list = ['Roots']
self.dirs_list = ['Dirs']
self.files_list = ['Files']
self.ctime_list = ['Date Created']
self.mtime_list = ['Date Modified']
self.selection_to_output_df = pd.DataFrame({})

for (root, dirs, files) in os.walk(path_to_crawl):
    self.roots_list.append(root)
    self.dirs_list.append(dirs)
    self.files_list.append(files)
    ### HOW TO GET ctime AND APPEND IT TO self.ctime_list? ###
    ### HOW TO GET mtime AND APPEND IT TO self.mtime_list? ###
    self.c += 1

roots_df = pd.DataFrame({'Roots': self.roots_list[1:]})
self.selection_to_output_df = pd.concat([self.selection_to_output_df, roots_df], axis=1)
dirs_df = pd.DataFrame({'Dirs': self.dirs_list[1:]})
self.selection_to_output_df = pd.concat([self.selection_to_output_df, dirs_df], axis=1)
files_df = pd.DataFrame({'Files': self.files_list[1:]})
self.selection_to_output_df = pd.concat([self.selection_to_output_df, files_df], axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, I found an example online and worked it up a little to fit my code:

```
global path_to_crawl
self.c = 0
self.files_list = ['File Path']
self.ctime_list = ['Date Created']
self.mtime_list = ['Date Modified']
self.selection_to_output_df = pd.DataFrame({})

for root, _, filenames in os.walk(path_to_crawl):
    for filename in filenames:
        file_path   = root + '/' + filename
        created     = os.path.getctime(file_path)
        modified    = os.path.getmtime(file_path)
        self.files_list.append(file_path)
        self.ctime_list.append(time.ctime(created))
        self.mtime_list.append(time.ctime(modified))                               
        self.c += 1

files_df = pd.DataFrame({'File Path': self.files_list[1:]})
self.selection_to_output_df = pd.concat([self.selection_to_output_df, files_df], axis=1)
created_df = pd.DataFrame({'Date Created': self.ctime_list[1:]})
self.selection_to_output_df = pd.concat([self.selection_to_output_df, created_df], axis=1)
modified_df = pd.DataFrame({'Date Modified': self.mtime_list[1:]})
self.selection_to_output_df = pd.concat([self.selection_to_output_df, modified_df], axis=1)
self.all_files_list = []
for sublist in self.files_list[1:]:
    for item in sublist:
        self.all_files_list.append(item)
return self.selection_to_output_df
```

Comment: It's impossible to visually do a diff, can you just explain briefly what you changed?

Comment: Also, it's more efficient to call `os.stat` once and extract `ctime`, `mtime` fields than separately call `os.path.getctime`, `os.path.getmtime` as @MaxGasner shows.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to call `os.stat`. Something like

```
stats = [os.stat(os.path.join(root, file)) for file in files]
self.ctime_list.append([stat.st_ctime for stat in stats])
self.mtime_list.append([stat.st_mtime for stat in stats])
```